# Display my ps3 on my Laptop Screen

Tags: windows, laptop, display, hdmi, ps3

I want to connect my **PS3** to my **Laptop Screen Display**, with a **HDMI** Cable, I want it only with HDMI or only AV I don't have anything else, and could you please explane it quite clear as I am not that a proffesional windows user.

p.s. I am also not sure if this question is within the scope of this community, if not then sorry I am new here and could you recommend maybe a place where I can ask this.

*I want to play with my on my ps3 and see through my Laptop Screen.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible without additional hardware. What you’d need is a HDMI grabber, like [these](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity). Of course, whether the latency induced by such a device would still be acceptable is yet another issue.

Comment: what do you mean there is no actual way to change the the display source of the laptop to the hdmi, with out any additional external hardware?

Comment: That’s right. All your laptop’s display connectors are *outputs*. That means they will not accept any incoming image data.

Comment: so this is definate, For sure. No way connectors can act as an input?, I am so Disspointed. any way thanks for making it clear

Comment: Yes, that’s right.